# Color values beyond a threshold in a table in R

Tags: r, colors, kable, kableextra

If I have the following table for the `mtcars` dataset:

```
knitr::kable(mtcars) %>%  
   kableExtra::kable_styling(c("bordered","condensed"), font_size = 15,full_width = T)
```

How can I color only the values (not cells) greater than, for example, 5 on that table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cell_spec` with `kable(escape = FALSE)` to predefine all cells' colors:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- mtcars
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ cell_spec(.x, color = ifelse(.x > 5, "red", "black")))) %>% 
  kable(escape = FALSE) %>%  
  kable_styling(c("bordered","condensed"), font_size = 15, full_width = T)
```

[image]